# Peticion ajax no reconoce la url de mi metodo en laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo un método en en el controlador laravel que recibe 7 parametros.

```
public function store($ruc, $business_name, $address, $phone, $item, $business_type, $uid)
    {
        try {                    
            $phone = filter_var($phone, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

            $company = array( 
                "ruc" => $ruc,
                "business_name" => $business_name,
                "address" => $address,
                "phone" => $phone,
                "item" => $item,
                "user_id" => $uid,
                "distrito_id" => 0,
                "isCompany" => $isCompany,
                "isProvider" => $isProvider);   

            $c_id = Company::select('id')->where("user_id","=", $uid)->first();

            if(!$c_id){
                $newcompany = Company::create($company);
                if($newcompany->save()){
                    return $this->sendResponse($newcompany, 'se guardo la compania correctamente');   
                }else{
                    return $this->sendError("ocurrio un error al guardar");
                }
            }else{
                return $this->sendError("ya tiene una compani registrada ene sta cuenta");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->sendError($e, strval( $e ) , 'se actualizo la informacion correctamente');
        }        
    }
```

Y mi ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::get('completeregister/{ruc}/{business_name}/{address}/{phone}/{item}/{business_type}/{uid}', 'Auth\RegisterController@store');
```

Cuando pongo esta url en el navegador me responde correctamente, lo que significa que la url si trabaja correctamente.
http://me.pruebalocal.com:8000/completeregister/123456789/empresa/ubicaion/telefono/rubro/2/2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando lo hago en una peticion ajax no encuentra la ruta y me genera el siguiente error: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Estoy haciendo mal la petición?. Este es mi codigo ajax:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://me.pruebalocal.com:8000/completeregister/123456789/empresa/ubicaion/telefono/rubro/2/2',
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (response) {
        if (response.success) {
          console.log(response.data);
        } 
      },
      error: function (response) {
        alert("Uno o mas datos ingreados son invalidos");  // 
      }
    });
```

Los parametros de la url van a cambiar de acuerdo a la peticion simplemente lo pongo todo junto para probar que reconosca la url ya que cuando pasaba parametros dinamicos como este: "ulr"+company tampoco lo reconocia

Comment: Si pruebas con Postman qué error te sale? Porque el 404 dice que no encuentra esa ruta.

Comment: Lo he probado con Soap Ui y no me sale ningun error

Comment: En tu pregunta dices que la url funciona correctamente, pero tiene un error en el ruc y te devuelve false en el success.

Comment: Eso es por la validacion y esta bien que me devuelva false eso significa que si valida el ruc, el problema esta en que no encuentra la url en ajax ni siquiera recibo una respuesta

Comment: La llamada ajax está en el mismo dominio que Laravel? Si es así puedes probar pasando la url sin la base y el puerto `'/completeregister/123456789/empresa/ubicaion/telefono/rubro/2/2'`

Comment: En el parametro URL del ajax, podrías cambiar `http://me.pruebalocal.com:8000/completeregister/123456789/empresa/ubicaion/telefono/rubro/2/2'` por `/completeregister/123456789/empresa/ubicaion/telefono/rubro/2/2'`

Comment: intente solo con esta url '/completeregister/123456789/empresa/ubicaion/telefono/rubro/2/2' y me sale el mismo error

Comment: Es una ruta que requiere autenticación? O tiene aplicado algún otro middleware?